# Why does the box keep moving after the brakes are fully applied?

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-physics, differential-equations, calculus

I made a minimal horizontal motion simulator with quadratic drag, which can be found [here](https://jsbin.com/mizonel/edit) (controlled with left and right arrow keys). As an exercise, I tried to implement braking in addition to applied force and drag. It works while the spacebar is held down, but the box starts moving again with a low speed in a seemingly random direction after it is released. Here is what I believe to be the relevant code:

```
let vt = 500 // terminal velocity
let amag = 1000 // magnitude of applied acceleration
let bmag = 1000 // magnitude of brake's acceleration
let drag = amag / (vt*vt) // coeffcient of quadratic drag

let x  = 0 // horizontal position
let vx = 0 // horizontal velocity

function update(timestamp) {
  let dt = ... // compute time delta from timestamp

  // current acceleration
  let ax = (keyStates.ArrowRight * amag) + (keyStates.ArrowLeft * -amag) - (keyStates[' '] * bmag * Math.sign(vx))

  // forward euler method; solves (x'(t), vx'(t)) = (vx(t), ax(t) - drag * vx(t)^2)
  x  += dt * vx
  vx += dt * (ax - Math.sign(vx) * drag * vx * vx)
}
```

Comment: Braking should be velocity dependent (as a linear friction term) (except if you are braking actively using some rocket engines). If the car is at rest, then stepping on the brake does not apply any acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

Your brake magnitude is larger than your `vx` when moving slowly. Additionally, your brake force applies opposite to the direction you're moving. Consequently, braking doesn't 0-out `vx`, but instead bounces `vx` around 0.

E.g. imagine `bmag = 1`, `dt = 1`, and `vx = 2.6`. Instead of `vx` going `2.6 -> 1.6 -> 0.6 -> 0`, it instead goes `2.6 -> 1.6 -> 0.6 -> -0.4 -> 0.6 -> -0.4...`

This is not noticeable while you're braking because the movements cancel each other out since it's constantly flipping direction. But once you release the brake, it continues at either `0.6` or `-0.4` depending on timing, hence your observed 'seemingly random direction'.

To fix this, simply zero out `vx` when `bmag * dt > vx`.

```
  // current acceleration
  let ax = (keyStates.ArrowRight * amag) + (keyStates.ArrowLeft * -amag);

  // forward euler method; solves (x'(t), vx'(t)) = (vx(t), ax(t) - drag * vx(t))
  x  += dt * vx
  vx += dt * (ax - Math.sign(vx) * drag * vx * vx)

  if (keyStates[' '])
     if (Math.abs(vx) > dt * bmag)
       vx -= dt * bmag * Math.sign(vx);
     else
       vx = 0;
```

BTW, thanks for providing both a reproducible example and a small subset that's relevant. It helps both potential repliers and future readers.